# Site shows without CSS for like 500ms after I added a random css script

Tags: javascript, html

I have added a javascript which loads a random css each time the site loads, and after I added this script, the website shows without CSS for a few milliseconds before showing normally

Here is the script:

```
(function() {
var sheet = document.createElement('link');
sheet.rel  = 'stylesheet';
sheet.href = 'css/' + (Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1) + '.css';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sheet);
})();
```

and here is where I put it in html
I have tried putting it outside the body and outside the head but still the same issue

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/random.js"></script>
<head>
```

Comment: Without CSS you will see the site... without CSS. Only after it's loaded can it be applied.

Comment: Your JS file needs to be loaded first. Try to put your code in `<script>` tag and place it as the first child element of your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Just load the css file normally using an inline `link` tag maybe?

Comment: have you tried loading js using `async` attribute? like `<script async type="text/javascript" src="js/random.js"></script>` , it will not block the rendering

Comment: yeah I have tried your suggestions guys if ive done them right, but none worked

Answer (score -1):

Fixed
new code:

```
var RANDOM_CSS = {
    cssfiles : ['1.css','2.css','3.css','4.css','5.css','6.css'],
    pathtocss : 'css/',
    getrandomcss : function() { return this.cssfiles[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.cssfiles.length)]; },
    getlinktag : function() { return '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+this.pathtocss+this.getrandomcss()+'" />'; },
    printlinktag : function() { document.write(this.getlinktag()); }
  };
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/random.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
RANDOM_CSS.printlinktag();
</script>
```